# How can I specify BaseType<any>?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a `WrapperBase<PocoBase>` class that wraps POCO objects and provides additional functionality:

```
public class WrapperBase<T> 
where T : PocoBase
```

and several implementations on top of that base class.

```
public class ButtonWrapper : WrapperBase<Button>
public class ZipperWrapper : WrapperBase<Zipper>
```

I'm trying to write a class that takes a `WrapperBase<T>` as a constructor parameter.

```
public class ThingDoer
   where T : PocoBase
{
    public ThingDoer(WrapperBase<T> wrapper)
    { 
    }
}
```

but no matter what I try, the `ThingDoer` wants a definition for `T`:

```
new ThingDoer<Zipper>(zipperWrapper);  
// I don't care what T is... get rid of <Zipper>
```

How can I say "I don't care what `T` is, because all the functionality I want is in `WrapperBase`"?

Comment: When working with generics, you have to imagine that the `<` and `>` are just part of the name. Imagine for a second you had your two classes defined as `public class ButtonWrapper : WrapperBase_Button` and `public class ZipperWrapper : WrapperBase_Zipper`, think about your question again, you can't just do `WrapperBase` because you don't have a class named `WrapperBase`, you have two classes named `WrapperBase_Button` and `WrapperBase_Zipper` that have nothing to do with each other at all other than they share the same first 12 letters in their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I say "I don't care what T is, because all the functionality I want is in WrapperBase"?

You could define an interface `IWrapperFunctionality` that specifies the methods providing that functionality. Have `WrapperBase<T>` implement that interface, and use it as your constructor argument.

```
public ThingDoer(IWrapperFunctionality wrapper)
{ 
}
```